# rviz don't follow the tf configuration of the .rviz file

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! My problem is that I want to display some of the TF and hide others. I can do it by selecting what I want by hand, but if I want to save it in a .rviz file and launching it with `rosrun rviz rviz -d my_config.rviz`, it display all my tf.

The .rviz file is well saved, here is an abstract of the /TF class in the my_config.rviz :

```
Visualization Manager:
Class: ""
  Displays:
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Cell Size: 1
      Class: rviz/Grid
      Color: 160; 160; 164
      Enabled: true
      Line Style:
        Line Width: 0.03
        Value: Lines
      Name: Grid
      Normal Cell Count: 0
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Plane: XY
      Plane Cell Count: 10
      Reference Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: true
    - Class: rviz/TF
      Enabled: true
      Frame Timeout: 15
      Frames:
        All Enabled: false

            WheelFL_link:
              Value: false
            WheelFR_link:
              Value: false
            ar_marker_1:
              Value: true
```

"my_config.rviz" is the right one loaded ( I tried to add and remove a display type to be sure ), and I am using the rviz version 1.11.7 (indigo), Compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208595/rviz-don%27t-follow-the-tf-configuration-of-the-.rviz-file/) by [scarlett](https://answers.ros.org/users/12086/scarlett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-05-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-07-29**:
I have the same issue, no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've experienced this as well. This appears to be a bug: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/834 (rather, a bug report has been filed).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2